# Django on Google App Engine: how to connect to cloud database to run makemigrations?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, proxy, port

I have been following [this](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#console_1) tutorial to create Django cloud app. I have been stuck on the 'Run the app on your local computer' part of the tutorial. Before running cloud_sql_proxy.exe command, I have created .env file and pasted its contents into Permissions on Google Cloud, so theoretically, after running set `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=PROJECT_ID`, I could delete this .env file from repository as it would recognize it anyway. But for now, I left it. What is more, I activate env correctly in the project dir when I ran command in this location, `gcloud sql instances describe INSTANCE_NAME` it works OK and displays database info.

[image]

Then, I have opened new Cloud SDK and ran command: `cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_NAME"=tcp:5434`.
The result is:

```
2021/11/08 17:11:11 Listening on 127.0.0.1:5434 for PROJECT_ID:REGION:INSTANCE_NAME  
2021/11/08 17:11:11 Ready for new connections  
2021/11/08 17:11:11 Generated RSA key in 116.9931ms
```

The reason behind why it is 5434 and not 5432 and 5433 as that these ports were busy. I must say that I have also downloaded postgresql and specified these:

[image: PEM server instalation details]
information.

After running in env (Google SDK) respectively:
`set GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=PROJECT_ID`
 `set USE_CLOUD_SQL_AUTH_PROXY=true`
`python manage.py makemigrations` , this error occurs:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\cloud\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard_python3\django\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py:105: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': FATAL:  database "DATABASE_NAME" does not exist

  warnings.warn(
No changes detected
```

I believe that it is because I must somehow know which port to use locally instead of 5434, to connect to a cloud through proxy. How to find this and fix the issue?

PS. note that i replaced real names to be PROJECT_ID, REGION, INSTANCE_NAME, DATABASE_NAME

Comment: Nowhere in the documentation it is mentioned to download the PEM server and specify the connection details. I am not sure why you have downloaded it. Can you clarify on that part? Also, have you followed the documentation properly?

Comment: @Prabir I've wanted to run app locally AND on cloud.

Comment: If you follow that document then you can find that it mentions how to run the app locally. For that no need to download and configure PEM server. You only have to run the Cloud SQL Proxy as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#run-locally).